# Dropping term for correlation between random effects in lme and interpretting summary output

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I want to fit a model without a correlation term between the random effects with `lme`. In `lmer` this is fairly straighforward....

```
# lmer without correlation term
m1 <- lmer(distance ~ (1|Subject) + age + (0+age|Subject) + Sex, data = Orthodont)
VarCorr(m1)
# Groups    Name        Std.Dev.
# Subject   (Intercept) 1.474105
# Subject.1 age         0.099979
# Residual              1.402591
```

With `lme` I think I can drop the correlation term using the following specification...

```
# lme without correlation term?
m2 <- lme(distance ~ age + Sex, data = Orthodont, random = list(~ 1 | Subject, ~-1+ age | Subject))
VarCorr(m2)
#             Variance            StdDev    
# Subject =   pdLogChol(1)                  
# (Intercept) 2.172946296         1.47409169
# Subject =   pdLogChol(-1 + age)           
# age         0.009996006         0.09998003
# Residual    1.967260819         1.40259075
```

I am not entirely convinced that these are the same models though, partly because I can not find any resources that details how to specify this specific form and partly because the output from `print` is a little mystifying to me...

```
m2 
# Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
#   Data: Orthodont 
#   Log-restricted-likelihood: -218.3227
#   Fixed: distance ~ age + Sex 
# (Intercept)         age   SexFemale 
#  17.5806928   0.6601852  -2.0117005 
# 
# Random effects:
#  Formula: ~1 | Subject
#         (Intercept)
# StdDev:    1.474092
# 
#  Formula: ~-1 + age | Subject %in% Subject
#                age Residual
# StdDev: 0.09998003 1.402591
# 
# Number of Observations: 108
# Number of Groups: 
#                Subject Subject.1 %in% Subject 
#                     27                     27
```

In particular, what is `Subject %in% Subject` referring to? and why are the residual considered as part of the second random effect term?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While in principle your approach works, this is not quite the 'standard' way of making the random intercepts and slopes uncorrelated. With `lme` you can use pdClasses (see `help(pdClasses)`) to give a particular structure to the variance-covariance matrix of the random effects. Here, you want to make that matrix diagonal. You can do that with:

```
m3 <- lme(distance ~ age + Sex, data = Orthodont, random = list(Subject = pdDiag(~ age))
m3

Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
  Data: Orthodont 
  Log-restricted-likelihood: -218.3227
  Fixed: distance ~ age + Sex 
(Intercept)         age   SexFemale 
 17.5806928   0.6601852  -2.0117005 

Random effects:
 Formula: ~age | Subject
 Structure: Diagonal
        (Intercept)        age Residual
StdDev:    1.474092 0.09998003 1.402591

Number of Observations: 108
Number of Groups: 27
```

You will find that the parameter estimates are actually identical to model `m2`, but the presentation of the results is more "logical".

Comment: Thanks, that is great. I have been exploring a little, and I think my `m2` has an extra hierarchy of `Subject` nested within `Subject`, hence the unexpected output.

Comment: Yes, that's what `Subject %in% Subject` means. But this obviously makes little sense. The results work out to be the same, but really using pdClasses is much more sensible here.