# Multivariate model in lme() with independent random effect, similar to MCMCglmm

Tags: r, mixed-model, multivariate-analysis, lme4-nlme

I would like to specify a multivariate model with `lme` with a random effect for group which is independent across variables. I found [this post](http://scs.math.yorku.ca/index.php/Mixed_Models_with_R/Multivariate_Mixed_Models.Rmd),
which explains that the model specified as:

```
fit.multilevel <- lme( y ~ var -1,  dd,
                    random = ~ var -1| school,   
                    correlation =  corSymm( form = ~ v |school/id), 
                    weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1 | v))
```

is equivalent to (using `MCMCglmm`):

```
fit.w.null <- MCMCglmm( cbind(mathach, ses) ~ trait -1 ,
        random = ~us(trait):school,   
        rcov = ~us(trait):units,
        data = hs,
        family = c("gaussian","gaussian"))
```

However the model I would really like has independent random effects for school across the variables:

```
fit.w.null <- MCMCglmm( cbind(mathach, ses) ~ trait -1 ,
        random = ~idh(trait):school,   
        rcov = ~us(trait):units,
        data = hs,
        family = c("gaussian","gaussian"))
```

(the random effect is specified with `idh()`). I cannot find a way to specify this in `lme`.
Here is some code to generate example data and run the analysis:

```
gr=rep(c("A","B","C"),each=100)
grp.mean=rep(rnorm(3,5,1),each=100)
var1=rnorm(300,rep(rnorm(3,5,1),each=100),1)
var2=0.8*var1+3*rnorm(300,rep(rnorm(3,5,1),each=100),2)
dat.mcmc=data.frame(var1=var1,var2=var2,group=gr)
dat.lme=data.frame(y=c(var1,var2),var=rep(c("1","2"),each=length(gr)),
             group=rep(gr,2),id=rep(1:length(gr),2))
dat.lme$v=as.integer(dat.lme$var)
```

Currently this is the best I can do:

```
fit.multilevel <- lme( y ~ var -1,  dat.lme,
                       random = ~ var -1| group,   
                       correlation =  corSymm( form = ~ v |group/id), 
                       weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1 | v))
```

This is (I believe) equivalent to:

```
fit.w.null <- MCMCglmm( cbind(var1, var2) ~ trait -1 ,
                        random = ~us(trait):group,   
                        rcov = ~us(trait):units,
                        data = dat.mcmc,
                        family = c("gaussian","gaussian"))
```

However, I would like an `lme` command equivalent to:

```
fit.w.null <- MCMCglmm( cbind(var1, var2) ~ trait -1 ,
                        random = ~idh(trait):group,   
                        rcov = ~us(trait):units,
                        data = hs,
                        family = c("gaussian","gaussian"))
```

Any help you can give me will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is to use `?pdClasses` as explained [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87050/dropping-term-for-correlation-between-random-effects-in-lme-and-interpretting-su?rq=1).

```
fit.multilevel <- lme( y ~ var -1,  dat.lme,
                   random = list(group= pdDiag(~ var-1)),    
                   correlation =  corSymm( form = ~ v |group/id), 
                   weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1 | v))
```